# Want to Extract Data in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using the HTTP request sampler, In which I have used Post Method. When I Execute the request, it executes another HTTP request from another thread.

I want to extract the data from that thread because the HTTP request contains a transaction id. I want to use that transaction id in the other threads.

The said transaction id is only showing in a pop up message in the resulting web page.

Kindly help me retrieve the transaction id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correlation.  There are a number of built in extractors, or you can write your own script to store the value in a variable.  What format is the transaction ID popup response ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can only extract data from response body, message, code, headers, or URL.

If you send the request which triggers another request and the data you're looking for is not in the 1st request response scope - unfortunately you won't be able to get it.

The only option I can think of is using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) which provider JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework so you would be able to execute the request and get the data from the popup using real browser.

WebDriver Sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)